# Errors in pip install flask-socketio

Tags: python, terminal, installation, pip, flask-socketio

I am trying to install flask-socketio from terminal

```
pip install flask-socketio
```

but it keep showing me the following error(in bold):

```
Collecting flask-socketio
  Using cached Flask-SocketIO-2.9.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.9 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from flask-socketio)
Collecting python-socketio>=1.5.0 (from flask-socketio)
  Using cached python-socketio-1.8.0.tar.gz
Collecting python-engineio>=1.0.0 (from flask-socketio)
  Using cached python-engineio-1.7.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.21 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.9->flask-socketio)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.7 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.9->flask-socketio)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.9->flask-socketio)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=2.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.9->flask-socketio)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from python-socketio>=1.5.0->flask-socketio)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask>=0.9->flask-socketio)
Installing collected packages: python-engineio, python-socketio, flask-socketio
  Running setup.py install for python-engineio ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/_g/m9lwl1yn5g5_wz3d57qc1qh40000gn/T/pip-build-1eGNas/python-engineio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/_g/m9lwl1yn5g5_wz3d57qc1qh40000gn/T/pip-U9szix-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/engineio
    copying engineio/__init__.py -> build/lib/engineio
    copying engineio/async_aiohttp.py -> build/lib/engineio
    copying engineio/async_eventlet.py -> build/lib/engineio
    copying engineio/async_gevent.py -> build/lib/engineio
    copying engineio/async_gevent_uwsgi.py -> build/lib/engineio
    copying engineio/async_sanic.py -> build/lib/engineio
    copying engineio/async_threading.py -> build/lib/engineio
    copying engineio/asyncio_server.py -> build/lib/engineio
    copying engineio/asyncio_socket.py -> build/lib/engineio
    copying engineio/exceptions.py -> build/lib/engineio
    copying engineio/middleware.py -> build/lib/engineio
    copying engineio/packet.py -> build/lib/engineio
    copying engineio/payload.py -> build/lib/engineio
    copying engineio/server.py -> build/lib/engineio
    copying engineio/socket.py -> build/lib/engineio
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to python_engineio.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing python_engineio.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to python_engineio.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to python_engineio.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'python_engineio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'README.md'
    writing manifest file 'python_engineio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running install_lib
    creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/engineio
    error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/engineio': Permission denied

    ----------------------------------------
**Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/_g/m9lwl1yn5g5_wz3d57qc1qh40000gn/T/pip-build-1eGNas/python-engineio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/_g/m9lwl1yn5g5_wz3d57qc1qh40000gn/T/pip-U9szix-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_g/m9lwl1yn5g5_wz3d57qc1qh40000gn/T/pip-build-1eGNas/python-engineio/**
```

I have tried updating my pip and basically went through mostly all related questions in stackoverflow but I am getting permission denied and its asking me to import some setup tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to install something to system python libs, try `sudo pip install flask-socketio`. Or use virtualenv

Comment: worked like a charm,
it also asked me to add -H with sudo, what is that for?

Comment: @pragya.go Why do you need flask in system packages anyway?

Comment: -H is to keep HOME environment variable to ypur home directory

Comment: was my answer useful?